# Can the discussion forum registration display custom fields?

Tags: templates, custom-fields, forum, registration

I'm using the Forum Module on a client site. I want to add two custom member fields to the registration form. Does anyone know if this is possible?

The theme template has a tag for custom fields, but they don't seem to show up.

```
{custom_fields}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
            {required}<span class="fm-required">*</span>{/required} {field_name}
            {if field_description}
                <span class="fm-field-notes">{field_description}</span>
            {/if}
        </th>
        <td class="fm-content-wrapper">
            {field}
        </td>
    </tr>
    {/custom_fields}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the "Edit Field" area of that member field and check if "Is field visible in registration page?" selected as "Yes".

Comment: Thank you. That was it. I turned the field on for the registration page. Much appreciated.

Comment: @AlexPereda: Great!!! Can you mark this answer as solution of your question.